# Problema ao retornar itens em um Relacionamento no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

Fala Pessoal Tudo certo!?

Estou passando pelo seguinte problema no entity framework que penso que seja algum erro que estou cometendo na hora de relacionar duas classes:

Tenho um Classe chamada: SolicitacaoGarantiaItemPecas que esta relacionada com um classe chamada Item, conforme figura abaixo, primeiro fiz o relacionamento entre elas diretamente na classe, mas como não estava funcionando tentei fazer por Fluent API conforme abaixo, estou conseguindo salvar no banco de dados normalmente mas quando vou fazer uma consulta alguns itens retornam normalmente mas outros não. o que pode ser? estou achando que tem a ver com o fato de que o relacionamento é com um campo do tipo string e não um código, será que pode ser isso?

Abaixo uma imagem com o exemplo do que esta ocorrendo, no mesmo list alguns objetos carregam e outros não, antes que me perguntem todos eles existem no banco e se eu consultar mais tarde eles retornam... pode ser alguma coisa com indice ou coisa parecida?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: Classes Relacionadas]

```
    public class SolicitacaoGarantiaItemPecas
{
    [Key]
    public int SolicitacaoGarantiaItemPecasID { get; set; }

    public string CodigoItem { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CodigoItem")]
    public virtual Item ItemPeca { get; set; }

    public decimal Quantidade { get; set; }
    public int CodPedido { get; set; }
    public string SituacaoPedido { get; set; }

    public int SolicitacaoGarantiaItemID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SolicitacaoGarantiaItemID")]
    public virtual SolicitacaoGarantiaItem SolicitacaoGarantiaItem { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SolicitacaoGarantiaItemPecas>().HasRequired(a => a.ItemPeca).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.CodigoItem);
```

Obrigado!
Alex

Comment: Deixe me ver se entendi bem. A mesma rotina, nas mesmas condições, por vezes retorna os relacionamentos e em outras vezes não retorna?

Comment: Isso mesmo Guilherme, mas ontem e descobri o problema, na minha tabela de itens a chave primaria estava em um campo texto sem especificar o tamanho, a key estava somente com um campo string o que fiz vou especificar um tamanho máximo para a chave e as FKs das outras classes  e a consulta começou a retornar todas as classes.         [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
        [StringLength(25)]
        [Key]
        public string CodigoItem { get; set; }

Comment: Dando `.Include( x => x.Entidade) ` não funcionaria ?

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver este problema ao que parece temos que especificar um tamanho máximo dos campos quando forem PK/FKs olha me pareceu estranho mas como estou trabalhando com Entity Framework a pouco tempo não sei dizer se isso é normal ou não, mas foi como consegui resolver, veja abaixo:

```
    Classe Item
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(25)]
    [Key]
    public string CodigoItem { get; set; }

    Classe SolicitacaoitemPecas
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string CodigoItem { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CodigoItem")]
    public virtual Item ItemPeca { get; set; }
```

Fazendo assim a coisa toda voltou a funcionar...